# Why doesn't this return statement work while the println() function works in Kotlin?

Tags: object, kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    CustomerData.count = 98
    CustomerData.typeOfCustomers()

    println(CustomerData.count)

}
```

```
object CustomerData {

     var count: Int = -1

     fun typeOfCustomers(){
         println("This came from typeOfCustomers function in CustomerData class")
     }

}
```

This prints "This came from typeOfCustomers function in CustomerData class" to console. But,  when I use return instead of println() that line doesn't return to console like below code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    CustomerData.count = 98
    CustomerData.typeOfCustomers()

    println(CustomerData.count)

}
```

```
object CustomerData {

     var count: Int = -1

     fun typeOfCustomers():String{
         return "This came from typeOfCustomers function in CustomerData class"
     }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Return just returns an object from the function. In your case, the object returned is a String. To print the string you would need to do this:

```
val typeOfCustomer = CustomerData.typeOfCustomers()

println("${CustomerData.count} $typeOfCustomer")
```

Answer (score 0):

Both your examples call `CustomerData.typeOfCustomers()`.

In the first example, that call writes the string directly to the console, which is why you see it.

In the second example, the call **returns the string but does nothing with it**, so the string is simply discarded.

Like most modern languages, in Kotlin the result of a function/method call is a value, and a value is always a valid statement; the value will simply be ignored unless you do something with it.

If you instead used that value in a `println()` call:

```
println(CustomerData.typeOfCustomers())
```

…then you'd see your string on the console as expected.  Or you could assign the result to a variable:

```
val type = CustomerData.typeOfCustomers()
```

Or use it in an expression:

```
val message = "Call returned: " + CustomerData.typeOfCustomers()
```

Or call one of its methods, or use it in any other way.

Otherwise, Kotlin will make the call but simply ignore the result.